# NoClassDefFoundError while starting up jetty Server

Tags: java, linux, spring, jetty

I am trying to host my webapp (spring) in jetty server. I copied my war file to the 'webapp' folder in the jetty server. I am not trying to embed the jetty server, but trying to host the app within the jetty (like tomcat).

I dint install jetty, I just downloaded the jetty7 zip and extracted to get the server.

I need to set this up in 3 linux machines. In One machine the server is starting up just fine.No issues.

But in the other two, when the Server is starting up it is showing the following error.

```
2013-04-24 18:52:59.540:INFO::started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/cpewebapp,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-9080-cpewebapp.war-_cpewebapp-any-/webapp/},/home/manooja/jetty-hightide-7.4.0.v20110414/webapps/cpewebapp.war
2013-04-24 18:52:59.648:WARN::FAILED spring: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/support/DefaultWebEnvironment
2013-04-24 18:52:59.648:WARN::FAILED o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/cpewebapp,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-9080-cpewebapp.war-_cpewebapp-any-/webapp/},/home/manooja/jetty-hightide-7.4.0.v20110414/webapps/cpewebapp.war: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/support/DefaultWebEnvironment
2013-04-24 18:52:59.649:WARN::Unable to reach node goal: started
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/support/DefaultWebEnvironment
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.(HttpServletBean.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.(FrameworkServlet.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.(DispatcherServlet.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createServlet(ServletContextHandler.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.newInstance(ServletHolder.java:748)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1220)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.parseCommandLine(Main.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:81)
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.support.DefaultWebEnvironment
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:373)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.(HttpServletBean.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.(FrameworkServlet.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.(DispatcherServlet.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createServlet(ServletContextHandler.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.newInstance(ServletHolder.java:748)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1220)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.parseCommandLine(Main.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:81)
2013-04-24 18:52:59.654:INFO::Deployable added: /home/manooja/jetty-hightide-7.4.0.v20110414/webapps/root
2013-04-24 18:52:59.849:INFO::started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/home/manooja/jetty-hightide-7.4.0.v20110414/webapps/root/},/home/manooja/jetty-hightide-7.4.0.v20110414/webapps/root
2013-04-24 18:52:59.861:INFO::Deployment monitor /home/manooja/jetty-hightide-7.4.0.v20110414/contexts at interval 1
2013-04-24 18:52:59.950:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9080 STARTING
```

Kindly note that the default port have been changed to 9080.

I have an inkling that it might be some configuration change, as it is working fine in one machine.
Could you please help me with a guidance to solve this?

> **java -jar start.jar --version**

```
    Active Options: [Server, client, ext, jmx, jsp, resources, websocket]
    Version Information on 25 entries in the classpath.
    Note: order presented here is how they would appear on the classpath.
          changes to the OPTIONS=[option,option,...] command line option will be reflected here.
     0:      9.0.2.v20130417 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-xml-9.0.2.v20130417.jar
     1:  3.0.0.v201112011016 | ${jetty.home}/lib/servlet-api-3.0.jar
     2:      9.0.2.v20130417 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-http-9.0.2.v20130417.jar
     3:      9.0.2.v20130417 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-continuation-9.0.2.v20130417.jar
     4:      9.0.2.v20130417 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-server-9.0.2.v20130417.jar
     5:      9.0.2.v20130417 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-security-9.0.2.v20130417.jar
     6:      9.0.2.v20130417 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-servlet-9.0.2.v20130417.jar
     7:      9.0.2.v20130417 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-webapp-9.0.2.v20130417.jar
     8:      9.0.2.v20130417 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-deploy-9.0.2.v20130417.jar
     9:      9.0.2.v20130417 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-client-9.0.2.v20130417.jar
    10:      9.0.2.v20130417 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-jmx-9.0.2.v20130417.jar
    11:  2.2.0.v201303151357 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/com.sun.el-2.2.0.v201303151357.jar
    12:  2.2.0.v201303151357 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/javax.el-2.2.0.v201303151357.jar
    13:  1.2.0.v201105211821 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.0.v201105211821.jar
    14:  2.2.0.v201112011158 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-2.2.0.v201112011158.jar
    15:  2.2.2.v201112011158 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/org.apache.jasper.glassfish-2.2.2.v201112011158.jar
    16:  1.2.0.v201112081803 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/org.apache.taglibs.standard.glassfish-1.2.0.v201112081803.jar
    17: 3.8.2.v20130121-145325 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.8.2.v20130121.jar
    18:                (dir) | ${jetty.home}/resources
    19:      9.0.2.v20130417 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-api-9.0.2.v20130417.jar
    20:      9.0.2.v20130417 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-common-9.0.2.v20130417.jar
    21:      9.0.2.v20130417 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-server-9.0.2.v20130417.jar
    22:      9.0.2.v20130417 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-servlet-9.0.2.v20130417.jar
    23:      9.0.2.v20130417 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-util-9.0.2.v20130417.jar
    24:      9.0.2.v20130417 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-io-9.0.2.v20130417.jar
```

> **dir ./WEB-INF/lib/**

```
antlr-2.7.6.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
bcprov-jdk15on-148.jar
c3p0-0.9.1.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-dbcp-1.3.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
cpewebapp.jar
displaytag-1.2.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
gson-1.6.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
hibernate-core-3.6.4.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.4.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.8.0.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.0.jar
javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
json.jar
jta.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
servlet-2.3.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-ldap-core-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-ldap-core-tiger-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-ldap-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.1.0.M1.jar
spring-web-servlet-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar
velocity-1.6.2.jar
velocity-tools-view-2.0.jar
```

Comment: How are you building the war? Looks like org.springframework.web.context.support.DefaultWebEnvironment is missing from the classpath ... perhaps it is (wrongly) on Jetty's classpath on the machine that is working? Is the spring support jar really inside the war?

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` means you are missing a class from your classpath. Find the jar containing `org.springframework.web.context.support.DefaultWebEnvironment` and add it to your classpath.

Comment: @stevie I am using ant build to build the war.
I do not want the Jetty to look for this class. This class belongs to Spring M1 (milestone) Jar, which is not good for production.
I am using Spring 3 RELEASE jar for spring support.

Comment: I have placed Spring 3 Release Jar in the lib folder as well.
I want jetty to take this jar.

Comment: _I do not want the Jetty to look for this class_ Something in your code needs the class, that's why java is trying to load it, but can't find it.

Comment: Exactly what version of Spring are you using? DefaultWebEnvironment appears to only exist in pre-release versions of 3.1.0 (appears it didn't make it into the release). I'd suggest you update to at least a release version of 3.1.x, or better still to the current 3.2.2 ... also DONT put any jars in Jetty's lib directory! (if that's what you meant)

Comment: @sotiriosDelima The mentioned class,.DefaultWebEnvironment, isnt there in any of the jar that i have included during build time. I have checked the class paths and jars.
Also in the machine that the jetty server is starting up, I dont have this jar.
Thats what stumped me.

Comment: @user2315838 That's exactly the point. It's needed by some other class you are using internally, but it's missing, so you are getting ClassNotFound. Maybe find which other class is using it.

Comment: @sotirios In the machine where there are no issues, i havent added the jar to include this class. But it works fine in there.

Comment: @soti I know I have made some mistake somewhere or missed a configuration entry that needs to be done. I just checked env varible $JETTY_HOME. It isnt set. Will that be a problem?

Comment: @user2315838 I don't know. Your best bet is figuring out which class uses the `DefaultWebEnvironment` (look at some javadoc) and figure out why it would use it as default, maybe you can set it to something else.

Comment: My guess is you have the wrong (or multiple) versions of the spring-web-support jar on your _compile_ classpath, and the correct one in your packaged war. Check your compile classpath. Alternatively, perhaps some other dependency on your classpath is using DefaultWebEnvironment?

Comment: Arbitrarily putting jars in ${jetty.home}/lib/ will do nothing.  use `$ java -jar start.jar --version` to see what jars jetty will load at the server side.  Also ... edit your question and paste a directory listing of your war file's `WEB-INF/lib/` folder.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Please find the listings tailed to the above question.
I did'nt put anything in the jetty lib. sorry for the confusion regarding the lib folder.

Comment: As a side note, I'll toss out that you should update to at least 7.6.10.v20130312 and run with the latest jvm for java6 or java7.  Not saying it will solve this issue but a lot of issues have been resolved since 7.4.4...and we have released jetty 9 already.

Comment: @Stevie You shoved me to the right path. Posting the answer now :)
Many thanks!

Comment: @jessemcconnell I am moving to the latest Jetty, 9. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Stevie pointed out in the comments,
the issue was an additional Jar file which got into the war.

I removed the Jar, in my case `spring-webmvc-3.1.0.M1.jar`, from `WEB-INF/lib` and restarted jetty.It started up fine.

This went unnoticed as it dint show up during compile/build time (got the jar ordered in eclipse), nor did it showed up in the first machine i deployed.

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your project config, like I use maven like this page.
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis/2.8.1

Then, when you use "update maven project" in eclipse et, it will download
the jedis.jar and other relationship files for complier. It will work in jetty to fix problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Although this may provide an answer to the question, you should always summarize your link's content, because they may be unavailable in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the case you use directly jetty as Eclipse J2EE integrated server, 
sometimes, it doesn't find some libraries (I don't understand why some are not found, by only a few), and throws exception of this kind (NoClassDefFound).

- So you have to put in the project source (directory WEB-INF): your jars
- restart the server
- it put the jars in runtime WEB-INF: 
  Data\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmpX\MyApp\WEB-INF\lib
- and it works.

Comment: I have this problem java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/jetty/Handler  already tried all maven of org.mortbay.jetty but can not find, open the .jar and contained that path